# How to get JSData DS#create() to persist to data store

Tags: angularjs, jsdata, js-data-angular

From the code below, I would expect the console value to increase every time I run the `save()` function. However, the number does not update. So I'm not seeing any created values injected into the store on create.

```
Budget = DS.defineResource('budget')

function save(){
      Budget.create(this.budgetItem, {upsert: true})
        .then( (   ) => {
          Budget.findAll().then((data)=>console.log(data.length))
        })
}
```

I'm using jsdata-angular.

After the first save `findAll()` executes it will retreive records from the server and then cache them. After that it does not make future calls to the server when performing a findAll() (this is expected behavior) however it is also not injecting the newly created values into store either.

All my configs are left unchanged. I'm using all defaults.

Comment: sure that `this` has valid context? If not passing undefined to `create()`

Comment: Try passing `useFilter: true` or `bypassCache: true` to `findAll` to see newly inserted items

Comment: thanks for checking my work, and yes, the item is not `undefined` and is actually getting created by the adapter (in this case `http` adapter is posting to a node/mongo back end). When i refresh my browser, the `findAll()` will go out and retrieve the the newly created item from the server just fine.

Comment: @jdobry `useFilter` did the trick? I'm going to check out docs to find out why my current usage was not working but advice would be a appreciated. THANKS FOR THE QUICK ANSWERS GUYS!

Comment: found the docs http://www.js-data.io/docs/dsfindall, i guess its pretty plain, just seems counter productive from everything you read before about it automatically updating the store.

Comment: The store is automatically updated, but the original query result cached by `findAll` is not. JSData cannot reliability know where to insert the newly created item into a particular cached query result, though the new item _has_ been inserted into the overall store. Personally, I never use the result of `findAll` directly in my View. Instead, `findAll` is for getting stuff _into_ the store, and `filter` is for selecting records out of a store to be used in a View.

Comment: @jdobry thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

`DS#findAll` is for retrieving records from a persistence layer via an adapter and loading them into the store. By default, if you make a `findAll` call and then make the exact same `findAll` call again (with the same `query` argument), then instead of making a new request, JSData returns to you the original result. You can change this behavior two ways:

- Set `useFilter` to `true` to have your `findAll` invocation call `DS#filter` and returning you the result.
- Set `bypassCache` to `true` to force the data to be reloaded via the adapter.

As a general rule of thumb, `findAll` is for asynchronously loading records into the store (e.g. via HTTP adapter GET request), and `filter` is for synchronously selecting records out of the store when you need them (e.g. display them in your View).

For example, in one place you do:

```
// Post records get retrieved and loaded into the store
store.findAll('post', { status: 'published }).then(...);
```

Then elsewhere:

```
// Need to display post records in your View
$scope.posts = store.filter('post', { status: 'published' });
```